# How to access attributes in a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I have two models

- absence: amount, staff_id
- staff: id, leave_balance

inside the absence model I want to edit the staff member which has their id inside staff_id and then I want to change their leave_balance but I do not know how to access that attribute in the staff model according to the staff_id in the current model using my method in absence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First have a look at the extensive [Rails Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to understand the concept.

Then you can do this:

**Staff.rb**

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :absence # or has_many :absence
end
```

**Absence.rb**

```
class Absence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :staff
end
```

Now you can access the attribute by, let's say, `Absence.first.staff.leave_balance -= 1` or within an instance method in the Absence model `self.staff.leave_balance = ...`

Comment: I should have mentioned I'd made the relationship between the two, I couldn't figure out why the database values were not updating and then it occurred to me I was not updating the database with the values :p

Comment: Glad you were able to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your relationships?

In the Absence class, you should have

```
belongs_to :staff
```

In the Staff class, you should have

```
has_many :absence
```

Once that's done, you can do things like:

```
a = Absence.last
a.staff.leave_balance -= 1
```

or

```
s = Staff.first
s.leave_balance -= s.absences.count
```